# How can i get from a window only the text without the Handle number?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two classes that get all the minimized windows:

The first class is WindowSnap.cs:

[WindowSnap.cs](http://pastebin.com/U4wgxQm7)

The second class is WindowSnapCollection.cs:

[WindowSnapCollection.cs](http://pastebin.com/TLe8gEDj)

In the first class in the windowSnap there is a method called GetAllWindows:

```
public static WindowSnapCollection GetAllWindows(bool minimized, bool specialCapturring)
        {
            windowSnaps = new WindowSnapCollection();
            countMinimizedWindows = minimized;//set minimized flag capture
            useSpecialCapturing = specialCapturring;//set specialcapturing flag
            EnumWindowsCallbackHandler callback = new EnumWindowsCallbackHandler(EnumWindowsCallback);
            EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);
            return new WindowSnapCollection(windowSnaps.ToArray(), true);
        }
```

In the end i used a breakpoint on the return line and windowSnaps variable contain 15 items.
For example the first item is:

[0] = {Window Text: , Handle: 31918532}

The second one is:

[3] = {Window Text: ?How can i get from a window only the text without the Handle number ? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome?, Handle: 64424060}

In the first item i was able to do on my own to remove this item since it's text is only "," and this window show nothing.

But number [3] and other items i want first to remove from them the part Handle: 64424060 
I don't need that the user will see this information. But only the text so for example number [3] should look like:

?How can i get from a window only the text without the Handle number ? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome?

And to fix those "?" that are in the beginning of the line.
But the idea is to display only the name of each window and not the whole text with the handle number.

This is how i add the items(windows) to form1 listBox:

```
this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```

In the listBox i want to see the items names or description/titles not the whole text with the handle number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little trick. It is not nice but works. Add a new listbox eg listBox1 with the same size on top of listBoxSnap.

add in `public Form1()`:

```
public Form1()
    {
        ...
        for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            if (tt.Contains(" ,"))
            {
                listBoxSnap.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        buttonSnap.Enabled = true;
//add here ->
        string[] myList = new string[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxSnap.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            int index = tt.LastIndexOf(",");
            myList [i] = tt.Substring(0, index);
        }

        listBox1.Items.AddRange(myList);

        rectangles = new Rectangle[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        isCropped = new bool[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];

        if (this.listBoxSnap.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            this.listBoxSnap.SetSelected(0, true);
            this.listBox1.SetSelected(0, true);
        }
        listBoxSnap.Select();
        listBox1.Select();
   }
```

change `private void listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` to:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

        drawpicbox(this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

and delete `this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged);` from `Form1.Designer.cs`

Add this event:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var item = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (item >= 0)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = item;
                listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
                cm.Show(listBox1, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

And lastly add in `private void RefreshWindowsList()`

```
private void RefreshWindowsList()
    {
        ...   
        for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            if (tt.Contains(" ,"))
            {
                listBoxSnap.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
//add here ->
        string[] myList = new string[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxSnap.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            int index = tt.LastIndexOf(",");
            myList [i] = tt.Substring(0, index);
        }

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(myList);

        rectangles = new Rectangle[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        isCropped = new bool[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];

        textBoxIndex.Text = listBoxSnap.Items.Count.ToString();
        if (this.listBoxSnap.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            this.listBoxSnap.SetSelected(0, true);
            this.listBox1.SetSelected(0, true);
        }
        listBoxSnap.Select();
        listBox1.Select();
    }
```

Valter